# cuda thrust based approach to grouping packets in tcp stream

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, thrust

I have tcpdumps (.pcap) files of captured packets with millions of packets. I need to group those network packets into TCP streams.

Example:
Let us consider the following packets
no => source_ip, destination_ip,source_port,destination_port

1 => ip1, ip2, s1, s2

2 => ip1, ip3, s3, s4

3 => ip2,ip1, s2, s1

4 => ip3,ip1, s4,s3

Now in the above example of four packets, packets 1,3 and 2,4 are the packets of same stream. i.e i need to resolve the following packets as [[1,3],[2,4]].

my approach:

Since (ip1, ip2, s1, s2) and (ip2, ip1, s2, s1) indicates same stream so I decided to hash both of them and name it as forward_hash and reverse hash as they denote packets of same stream flowing in opposite directions.

I use an index array to keep track of the packets during replacing and sorting. After final sorting, the starting and ending of same hashes is extracted and used against index array to get the packet indices that represent that stream

```
keys is the forward_hash of each packets, 
count is number of packets, 
packet_ids is the id of each packet corresponding to each of the hash

    thrust::device_vector<unsigned long long> d_keys(keys,(keys+count));
            thrust::device_vector<unsigned long long> d_ids(packet_ids,(packet_ids+count));
            // now sort the ids according to the keys
            thrust::sort_by_key(d_keys.begin(), d_keys.end(), d_ids.begin());
// after sorting, now we need to find the index of each hash
thrust::device_vector<unsigned long long> u_keys(count);
        thrust::device_vector<unsigned long long> output(count);

        thrust::pair<thrust::device_vector<unsigned long long>::iterator, thrust::device_vector<unsigned long long>::iterator> new_end;
        new_end = thrust::reduce_by_key(d_keys.begin(), d_keys.end(),thrust::make_constant_iterator(1),u_keys.begin(),output.begin());
// now we need to find starting index to each hash
....
```

I've tried to implement hash table lookup for unique forward and reverse hash but for replacing every reverse hash with forward hash before sorting...but is quite slow on performance. I 
Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose another approach which first sorts **within** each packet and then sorts the packets.

The example code does the following steps:

1. In order to identify packets of the same TCP stream, we need to sort the packets.
   Before we can do that, we need to make sure that **within** each sent packet source and destination are sorted.
   Example: `20:1 -> 10:4` becomes `10:4 -> 20:1`
2. Now we can sort the packets so that packets of the same stream are grouped.
   This code assumes that the input packets are sorted in time. We apply a **stable** sort in order to keep the sorting within each stream.
3. We need to find out where each TCP stream starts. The result of this step are indices which point to the beginning of a TCP stream in the sorted packet list.
4. Depending on how you need the result, we can generate additional information about the streams such as number of packets per stream.

Possible improvement:

If you know that IP addresses are only of a certain limited range, they might be represented using just 16 bit.
You could then possibly compress sender address, sender port, receiver address, receiver port into a 64bit integer which will improve sort performance.

---

**compile and run**

```
nvcc -std=c++11 sort_packets.cu -o sort_packets && ./sort_packets
```

---

**output**

```
input data
d_src_addr: 20  10  20  20  30  30  10  20  30  20  
d_src_port: 1   2   3   1   2   2   6   1   1   1   
d_dst_addr: 10  20  30  10  20  20  30  10  10  10  
d_dst_port: 4   2   3   4   5   5   1   4   6   4   

packets after sort_within_packet
d_src_addr: 10  10  20  10  20  20  10  10  10  10  
d_src_port: 4   2   3   4   5   5   6   4   6   4   
d_dst_addr: 20  20  30  20  30  30  30  20  30  20  
d_dst_port: 1   2   3   1   2   2   1   1   1   1   

after stable_sort
d_orig_ind: 1   0   3   7   9   6   8   2   4   5   

packets after stable_sort
d_src_addr: 10  10  10  10  10  10  10  20  20  20  
d_src_port: 2   4   4   4   4   6   6   3   5   5   
d_dst_addr: 20  20  20  20  20  30  30  30  30  30  
d_dst_port: 2   1   1   1   1   1   1   3   2   2   

after copy_if
d_start_indices:    0   1   5   7   8   
d_stream_lengths:   1   4   2   1   2   

group of streams referencing the original indices
[1] [0,3,7,9]   [6,8]   [2] [4,5]
```

---

**sort_packets.cu**

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/adjacent_difference.h>
#include <thrust/scatter.h>


#define PRINTER(name) print(#name, (name))
template <template <typename...> class V, typename T, typename ...Args>
void print(const char* name, const V<T,Args...> & v)
{
    std::cout << name << ":\t";
    thrust::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, "\t"));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

typedef thrust::tuple<uint32_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint16_t> Packet;

struct sort_within_packet : public thrust::unary_function<Packet, Packet>
{
    __host__ __device__
    Packet operator()(Packet p) const
    {
        if (thrust::get<0>(p) > thrust::get<2>(p))
        {
            Packet copy(p);
            thrust::get<0>(p) = thrust::get<2>(copy);
            thrust::get<1>(p) = thrust::get<3>(copy);
            thrust::get<2>(p) = thrust::get<0>(copy);
            thrust::get<3>(p) = thrust::get<1>(copy);
        }
        return p;
    }
};

struct find_start_indices : public thrust::unary_function<thrust::tuple<Packet, Packet>, bool>
{
    __host__ __device__
    bool operator()(thrust::tuple<Packet, Packet> p)
    {
       return (thrust::get<0>(p) != thrust::get<1>(p));
    }
};

template<typename... Iterators>
__host__ __device__
thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<Iterators...>> zip(Iterators... its)
{
    return thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(its...));
}


int main()
{
    // in this example we just have 10 packets
    const int N = 10;

    // demo data
    // this example uses very simple "IP addresses"
    uint32_t srcAddrArray[N] = {20, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 10, 20, 30, 20};
    uint16_t srcPortArray[N] = {1 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 6 , 1 , 1 , 1 };

    uint32_t dstAddrArray[N] = {10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 20, 30, 10, 10, 10};
    uint16_t dstPortArray[N] = {4 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 5 , 1 , 4 , 6 , 4 };

    // upload data to GPU
    thrust::device_vector<uint32_t> d_src_addr(srcAddrArray, srcAddrArray+N);
    thrust::device_vector<uint16_t> d_src_port(srcPortArray, srcPortArray+N);

    thrust::device_vector<uint32_t> d_dst_addr(dstAddrArray, dstAddrArray+N);
    thrust::device_vector<uint16_t> d_dst_port(dstPortArray, dstPortArray+N);

    thrust::device_vector<uint32_t> d_orig_ind(N);
    thrust::sequence(d_orig_ind.begin(), d_orig_ind.end());

    std::cout << "input data" << std::endl;
    PRINTER(d_src_addr); PRINTER(d_src_port); PRINTER(d_dst_addr); PRINTER(d_dst_port); std::cout << std::endl;

    // 1. sort within packet
    auto zip_begin = zip(d_src_addr.begin(), d_src_port.begin(), d_dst_addr.begin(), d_dst_port.begin());
    auto zip_end   = zip(d_src_addr.end(),   d_src_port.end(),   d_dst_addr.end(),   d_dst_port.end());
    thrust::transform(zip_begin, zip_end, zip_begin, sort_within_packet());

    std::cout << "packets after sort_within_packet" << std::endl;
    PRINTER(d_src_addr); PRINTER(d_src_port); PRINTER(d_dst_addr); PRINTER(d_dst_port); std::cout << std::endl;

    // 2. sort packets
    thrust::stable_sort(zip(d_src_addr.begin(), d_src_port.begin(), d_dst_addr.begin(), d_dst_port.begin(), d_orig_ind.begin()),
                        zip(d_src_addr.end(),   d_src_port.end(),   d_dst_addr.end(),   d_dst_port.end(),   d_orig_ind.end()));

    std::cout << "after stable_sort" << std::endl;
    PRINTER(d_orig_ind); std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "packets after stable_sort" << std::endl;
    PRINTER(d_src_addr); PRINTER(d_src_port); PRINTER(d_dst_addr); PRINTER(d_dst_port); std::cout << std::endl;

    // 3. find stard indices of each stream
    thrust::device_vector<uint32_t> d_start_indices(N);

    using namespace thrust::placeholders;
    thrust::device_vector<uint32_t>::iterator copyEnd = thrust::copy_if(thrust::make_counting_iterator(1), thrust::make_counting_iterator(N),
                                                                            thrust::make_transform_iterator(
                                                                               zip(
                                                                                   zip(d_src_addr.begin(), d_src_port.begin(), d_dst_addr.begin(), d_dst_port.begin()),
                                                                                   zip(d_src_addr.begin()+1, d_src_port.begin()+1, d_dst_addr.begin()+1, d_dst_port.begin()+1)  
                                                                                ),
                                                                                find_start_indices()
                                                                            ),
                                                                            d_start_indices.begin()+1, _1);

    uint32_t streamCount = copyEnd-d_start_indices.begin();
    d_start_indices.resize(streamCount);

    std::cout << "after copy_if" << std::endl;
    PRINTER(d_start_indices);

    // 4. generate some additional information about the result and print result formatted
    thrust::device_vector<uint32_t> d_stream_lengths(streamCount+1);
    thrust::adjacent_difference(d_start_indices.begin(), d_start_indices.end(), d_stream_lengths.begin());
    d_stream_lengths.erase(d_stream_lengths.begin());
    d_stream_lengths.back() = N-d_start_indices.back();
    PRINTER(d_stream_lengths);

    thrust::host_vector<uint32_t> h_start_indices = d_start_indices;
    thrust::host_vector<uint32_t> h_orig_ind = d_orig_ind;

    auto index = h_start_indices.begin();
    index++;

    std::cout << std::endl << "group of streams referencing the original indices"<< std::endl <<  "[" <<  h_orig_ind[0];
    for(int i=1; i<N;++i)
    {
      if (i == *index)
      {
         index++;
         std::cout << "]\t[";
      }
      else
      {
         std::cout << ",";
      }
      std::cout << h_orig_ind[i];
    }
    std::cout << "]" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It keeps me giving this error

error: no instance of function template "zip" matches the argument list
??

Comment: @rawcoder this code requires C++11 features, see **compile and run** above. this will work with CUDA7 and a recent compiler such as GCC 4.8

Comment: @rawcoder you could of course rewrite the usage of `zip` with the standard `thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(...))` and replace `auto` by the actual types, it's just a lot to write then

Comment: I'm using CUDA6.5 and gcc 4.8

Comment: @rawcoder Is there anything that prevents you from upgrading to CUDA 7?